# Can I have sequential record number/total records number in access subform?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am looking for a VBA code which lets me have sequential record number/total records number in Microsoft access **subform**, for example, if I have 3 records, a certain field "textbox" will display:
1/3,
2/3 and
3/3
and if I add another record, then it will show:
1/4,
2/4,
3/4,
4/4 and so on...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you have an autoincrement field in your table e.g. ID you can use it like this

Controlsource of a Textbox:

```
=DCount("*";"YourTable";"ID <= " & [ID]) & "/" & Count("*")
```

Hope this works. if you have a syntay error replace ; with ,. I have a german access version, so the syntax i little bit different.

Comment: The AutoNumber field may not be sequential, it will be unique though.  Maybe use the `DMAX` function to increment a value within your table:  `DMax("ID", "MyTable") + 1`.  Your record numbering won't be sequential if you delete a record though.

Comment: This function will return the total number of the records in a subform  but it won't display the subform record textbox as 1/3 (means 1 out of 3), 2/3, 3/3 and so on. I have a main form for a patient ID. One patient may have multiple MRIs. I want to display the sequential number of this MRI/ total number of MRIs for this patient, in the mri_accession textbox and save the auto-populated value directly to MRI_accession field" in the MRI_table ".